# Charm 4.0.1 possibility to disable layout adjustment when keyboard shows up

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I'm facing several problems with the new function which is responsible for adjusting the view layout, when the keyboard shows up.

For example when a `DatePicker` is shown while a `TextField` is focused:

[image]

Is there a possibility to disable this function?

**EDIT:**

While removing the focus from the `TextField` before the `DatePicker` is shown works, there are still some others issues so I would prefer to use my own custom solution [AndroidNodePositionAdjuster](https://github.com/j-ns/Orienteering/blob/master/Orienteering/src/android/java/com/jns/orienteering/platform/AndroidNodePositionAdjuster.java).

Another issue e.g. is an unpleasant white area (which will be covered by the keyboard), when the view is transitioned upwards to make room for the soft keyboard, so the transition appears very unsmooth:

[image]

Comment: If I get it right, you have the textfield (the counter) focused, so the soft keyboard is visible. Then instead of typing, you click on the date (let's say a Label, not focusable) and display the DatePicker, but the soft keyboard is still visible. I think you should remove the focus of the textField before showing the DatePicker. Even `dateLabel.requestFocus()` will work.

Comment: Yes, that works (I've already tried that, but obviously with a not focusable node...). Still there are some other issues which I've described in my edited question

Comment: My keyboard shows up immediately, I don't see that white area

Comment: I see it on a Huawei Android 4.1 and on a Google Pixel C Android 7.0. My AndroidNodePositionAdjuster is disabled

Comment: When the keyboard shows up/hides, it is really fast (tested with Nexus 6, Pixel C).

Comment: Obviously my oldfashioned Huawei doesn't meet modern requirements. I exchanged it for a more up-to-date Huawei P9 lite, and changed the backgroundcolor of the bottombar to a light grey shade, which solved the white area issue (or made it less noticable). Still the layout adjustment is working very unreliable. Every now and then it just stops working for one adjustment and the focused input Node is left covered by the keyboard.

Comment: @JoséPereda After a lot of trial and error, I have the impression that the `adjustment function` doesn't play well with a `ScrollPane`. When you `touch and release` for e.g. a `TextField`in a ScrollPane in a lot of cases the view layout won't get adjusted, but if you `touch and don't release` (touch_stationary) it is always working (jfxmobile 1.3.1, charm 4.3.0)