# Gluon View layout displaced after taking a picture

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

When my app is resumed after taking a picture, the layout of the view is displaced:

[image]
[image]

This effect only occurs when an input node, e.g. `TextField` was focused and the layout had to be adjusted in order to not make the keyboard cover the input node. Even more interessting, I couldn't reproduce the issue while selecting a picture.

The error occurred when I updated Android 6.0 to 7.0

**Edit:**
Every now and then, there is a similar error, when the keyboard is hidden (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369618/charm-4-0-1-possibility-to-disable-layout-adjustment-when-keyboard-shows-up)):

[image]

Comment: How is it possible that you keep the focus on a TextField, while clicking a button to trigger the pictures service? Doesn't the focus move to that button?

Comment: I've noticed a possible issue that has nothing to do with a TextField. When opening the camera, if you cancel it (or press the back button), there is a visible vertical layout adjustment (just a few pixels). This doesn't happen with the gallery. Is this what you are noticing too?

Comment: You're right. The focus will be set to the camera button. I don't notice any layout adjustment, as long as the keyboard is not shown. I've updated my question

Comment: In the new picture you've posted, it seems the view is displaced vertically a few pixels. If you tap on it, will it adjust to the correct position? I noticed that was happening right after cancelling the camera in some occasions.

Comment: Yes it will. But when a textfield receives and loses the focus again, the layout won't be set back to its original position, i.e. there remains a white area about the size of the keyboard.

Comment: So there are two overlapping issues: once the camera layer is closed, the original JavaFX layer is misplaced (1), and while it can be adjusted, if we open and close the keyboard, its final position will be wrong (2). Is that it?

Comment: Basically yes, however the JavaFX layer can't be adjusted, when there already happened a layout adjustment prio to using the camera.

Comment: Ok, I've filed an issue, thanks for reporting.

Comment: @jns is the app open source? I once thought about creating one like this as well, but never got over the state of planning. Yours already is looking pretty good!

Comment: It's not open source. I put quite some effort into developing the app, and it's more complex than the pics might suggest. To some extent it is based on the code you can find [here](https://github.com/j-ns/Orienteering), while a huge part, especially the data handling, was completely  redesigned or replaced.